# Why can I not cast to a generic interface from a type with a generic argument which is a subtype of the generic argument in my interface?

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following interface:

```
public interface IController<T> where T: Request {
    Response HandleRequest(T request);
}
```

And the following Request class:

```
public BlergRequest : Request {
}
```

And the following controller implementation:

```
public BlergController : IController<BlergRequest> {
    public Response HandleRequest(BlergRequest request) {
        return new Response("Here's your blergs!");
    }
}
```

Why is the following an `InvalidCastException`?

```
IController<Request> controller = (IController<Request>)new BlergController();
```

In my "Immediate" window in the debugger, I have the following:

```
typeof(Request).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BlergRequest))
true

typeof(IController<Request>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BlergController))
false
```

What gives? I thought this was the whole point of generic constraints?

Comment: What would happen if it worked, and then you called `controller.HandleRequest(someNonBlergRequest);`? `HandleRequest` could easily be accessing Blerg specific fields..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you're not allowed to do this is perfectly logical from a type safety perspective. If an `IController<BlergRequest>` accepts `BlergRequests` in various methods (in your example, `HandleRequest` is one such method), it stands to reason that those methods might invoke members that are **only** available on a `BlergRequest`, and not on a `Request`. Thus you can't assign (or cast) an `IController<BlergRequest>` to an `IController<Request>`.

If on the other hand your interface was only **returning** `BlergRequest`s, and never consumed them, then it could return a `BlergRequest` to any consuming code that required a `Request`. In such a case, your interface would be **covariant** in `T`, and you could mark the type parameter `T` with the covariant `out` modifier. You could then assign `IController<BlergRequest>` wherever an `IController<Request>` is needed.

Comment: Makes perfect sense - bit ashamed I didn't realize that before posting. My idea was that I could make a RequestRouter which searched the assembly for IController instances and routed requests appropriately. In my code I was doing something like `var controllers = new Dictionary<Type, IController<Request>>(); ... ; controllers.Add(requestType, controllerCtor.Invoke(...) as IController<Request>);` Obviously that gave me a dictionary which contains a bunch of `null` values.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on @Asad's comment; try this:

```
public class Request { }
public class Response {
  public Response(string text) {}
}

public interface IController<out T> where T: Request {
    Response HandleRequest(T request);
}

public class BlergRequest : Request { }

public class BlergController : IController<BlergRequest> {
    public Response HandleRequest(BlergRequest request) {
        return new Response("Here's your blergs!");
    }

    public void Test() {
      IController<Request> controller = new BlergController();
    }
}
```

However, the argument to IController.HandleRequest is (probably) not *covariant* as written. Extending the use of interfaces however, makes this compile cleanly without a specification of variance, which may meet your needs:

```
public interface IRequest { }

public class Request : IRequest { }
public class Response {
  public Response(string text) {}
}

public interface IController<T> where T: IRequest {
    Response HandleRequest(T request);
}

public class BlergRequest : IRequest { }

public class BlergController : IController<IRequest> {
    public Response HandleRequest(BlergRequest request) {
        return new Response("Here's your blergs!");
    }

    public void Test() {
      IController<IRequest> controller = new BlergController();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I just realized a problem here. The class isn't defined covariantly wrt the type parameter, so it's type parameter can't be made covariant. There's a method that accepts an argument of type `T`, which contradicts the requirement that the class be covariant.

Comment: You can't do this, "The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid" etc etc - you can only **return** T for out type parameters, not receive them as parameters.

Comment: In your second code-block, your `BlergController` does not implement its interface..